# A very strange character

Tags: riddle, knowledge

1. My mouth can kill, but my eyes can only damage.
2. Religious people turn into atheists because of the offhand positions my golf ball is in.
3. I conceal what I wish to, as small people tend to do.
4. I'm an air-traffic controller in Dallas, telling some planes to go and others not to.
5. I sometimes want you to give me the facts, but I don't accept them.
6. I like a really good discount, especially of the five-finger variety.
7. I have no aide.
8. I tend to be early to things, without collapsing or capitulating.
9. I've performed a brain transplant. On myself!
10. I'll promise to give you the entire book of Genesis, and act out 4:23.
11. I'm a hospital clown, taking samples of both diseased and healthy blood. Generally I'm nice about it, but sometimes my Mr. Hyde side comes out. As a hospital clown, I'm self-employed, so I set my own working conditions and won't be detained.
12. I have a fever of 38°C, and it's my own fault.
13. I'll do nothing more than insult you.

Who am I?

Comment: Are you okay????

Comment: Are you emojis?

Comment: I'm afraid not, @Dannyu.

Comment: Really enjoyed this. The Dallas bit was genius.And I liked the rot13("V..." ba rirel yvar. Avpr zvfqverpgvba.)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You are

> Always a woman (to me ... well, to Billy Joel anyway)

These are the

> [Song lyrics](https://genius.com/Billy-joel-shes-always-a-woman-lyrics) rewritten

1. My mouth can kill, but my eyes can only damage.

   > She can kill with a smile, she can wound with her eyes
2. Religious people turn into atheists because of the offhand **positions my golf ball is** in.

   > She can ruin your faith with her casual **lies**
3. I conceal what I wish to, as small people tend to do.

   > And she only reveals what she wants you to see / She hides like a child but she's always a woman to me
4. I'm an air-traffic controller in Dallas, telling some planes to go and others not to.

   > She can lead you to [Love](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dallas_Love_Field), she can take you or leave you
5. I sometimes want you to give me the facts, but I don't accept them.

   > She can ask for the truth but she'll never believe you
6. I like a really good discount, especially of the five-finger variety.

   > And she'll take what you give her as long as it's free / Yeah she steals like a thief but she's always a woman to me
7. I have no aide.

   > Oh, she takes care of herself
8. I tend to be early to things, without collapsing or capitulating.

   > she can wait if she wants / She's ahead of her time / Oh, she never gives out and she never gives in
9. I've performed a brain transplant. On myself!

   > She just changes her mind
10. I'll promise to give you the entire book of Genesis, and act out 4:23.

    > And she'll promise you more than the garden of Eden / Then she'll carelessly cut you
11. I'm a hospital clown, taking samples of both diseased and healthy blood. Generally I'm nice about it, but sometimes my Mr. Hyde side comes out. As a hospital **clown**, I'm self-employed, so I set my own working conditions and won't be detained.

    > and laugh while you're bleeding / But she brings out the best and the worst you can be / ...chorus... / She is frequently kind and she's suddenly cruel / She can do as she pleases, she's nobody's **fool** / But she can't be convicted,
12. I have a fever of 38°C, and it's my own fault.

    > She's earned her degree
13. I'll do nothing more than insult you.

    > And the most she will do is throw shadows at you .... chorus

Comment: Finally someone else has the same idea as me! So now I'll dump a few of my ideas, none of which were enough to get me to post anything :-). It seems like rot13(gurl ner yvxryl qvssrerag fbatf ol gur fnzr negvfg) though I also wondered whether they might instead rot13(nyy or _nobhg_ n pbzzba "punenpgre", znlor "lbh"). The title made me wonder about rot13(Cevapr) but I couldn't find any matches at all. 1 made me wonder about rot13("vs ybbxf pbhyq xvyy" naq eryngrq vqrnf). 12 is rot13(_bar uhaqerq qrterrf_ S). I agree about 6 and probably 7. Your remark on 2 is a really good spot; I missed it.

Comment: Could conceivably be something like rot13(zbivr yvarf) rather than rot13(fbat ylevpf) but the latter does seem more likely. Second half of 10 is about rot13(xvyyvat fbzrbar) but there are a zillion options there. 8 puts me in mind of rot13(gung snzbhf Evpx Nfgyrl ahzore hfrq sbe cenaxvat: "yrg lbh qbja", "tvir lbh hc") but I think that's probably coincidence. The ones that seem like they should be the biggest giveaways are 4 and 11 but I have no ideas at all for them. I know basically nothing about rot13(rvgure zbivrf be cbchyne zhfvp) so I'm glad to see someone else on it...

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! Agree 4 and 11 seem like they should break it open. The one problem with rot13( qvssrerag fbatf ol gur fnzr negvfg) is that they're very generic. Unfortuntely I know nothing about rot13(rvgure zbivrf) either!

Comment: Actually, #4 might refer to rot13(Qnyynf Ybir nvesvryq)? Might be more in keeping with the theme

Comment: Well done, very clever.

Comment: Thanks. Weirdly, it was the first line that gave it to me in the end. I was looking up things like rot13(Znarngre) (miles off) when this suddenly popped into my head through some weird subconscious association

Comment: Well done! I've edited slightly to reflect my intent; feel free to revert.

Comment: Splendid! (No way I was going to get any of this; I don't know that rot13(fbat) at all. I'm afraid I'm highly unconvinced by 11, by the way...)

Comment: @msh210 Edit is fine, I figured there was a crossover somewhere between 10 and 11, just wasn't sure where to break it.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably wrong, but:

> a washer/dryer combo?
>  It runs hot, steals socks, hides things, can kill, takes blood out of hospital sheets, beeps angrily when it's done, and you could maybe use golf balls as laundry balls?

Comment: Not it, I'm afraid.

Answer (score -1):

I'm probably wrong, but I believe this could be:

> Pennywise the clown? He does eat people, and his mentions in media have multiple references to the Bible. He also has no aide, but I'm not sure how he applies to the other clues.

Comment: Not it, I'm afraid.

Answer (score -1):

Partial answer, but I think this is

> A pandemic, plague, flu, virus or infection

1. <s>My mouth can kill, but my eyes can only damage.</s>
2. <s>Religious people turn into atheists because of the offhand positions my golf ball is in.</s>
3. I conceal what I wish to, as small people tend to do.

> Incubation period

4. I'm an air-traffic controller in Dallas, telling some planes to go and others not to.

> Flights grounded in quarantined zones

5. I sometimes want you to give me the facts, but I don't accept them.

> *Perhaps* this relates to anti-vaxxers?

6. I like a really good discount, especially of the five-finger variety.

> Loss of digits due to necrosis/gangrene/infection

7. I have no aide.

> Medical aid? Not sure how to fit this

8. <s>I tend to be early to things, without collapsing or capitulating.</s>
9. I've performed a brain transplant. On myself!

> A virus splitting/invading another cell

I'll promise to give you the entire book of Genesis, and act out 4:23.

> Not fluent in the bible, but there were certainly curses and plagues mentioned. Also, being wounded or injured is a good way to get an infection.

I'm a hospital clown, taking samples of both diseased and healthy blood. Generally I'm nice about it, but sometimes my Mr. Hyde side comes out. As a hospital clown, I'm self-employed, so I set my own working conditions and won't be detained.

> Not really sure, but the story of Jekyll and Hyde involves a serum/poison/antidote.

I have a fever of 38°C, and it's my own fault.

> Pretty self-explanatory here

I'll do nothing more than insult you.

> Could be seen as a curse

Comment: Not it, I'm afraid.